# How to use sweetalert2 chaining modal as a quiz

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using sweetalert2 and would like to make a quiz out of it's chaining modal where my users will input the value of the correct answer.
For example :

Question : Who is Jesus ?
1 - Only The Son of God
2 - Only God
3 - God and at the same time the son of God

The user will have to input 1 or 2 or 3 in the input file.

After I edited the sweet alert code and added the list code

```
<ol>
<li>only the son of God </li>
<li>only God </li>
<li>God and at the same time the son of God</li>
</ol>
```

Instead of Sweetalert2 interpreting the code, it displayed the code.

```
 $('.examples .chaining-modals button').on('click', function () {
    swal.setDefaults({
      input: 'text',
      confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
      showCancelButton: true,
      progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
    })

    var steps = [
      {title: 'Question : Who is Jesus ?', text: '<ol><li>only the son of God </li> <li>only God </li>    <li>God and at the same time the son of God</li>   </ol>'},
      {title: 'The Holy Spirit is the Spirit of Jesus', text: 'True or False'},
      {title: 'The Holy Spirit is a woman', text: 'True or False'}
    ]

    swal.queue(steps).then(function (result) {
      swal.resetDefaults()
      swal({
        title: 'All done!',
        html: 'Your answers: <pre>' + JSON.stringify(result) + '</pre>',
        confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
      }).catch(swal.noop)
    }, function () {
      swal.resetDefaults()
    })
  })
```

How to use sweetalert2 chaining modal as a quiz ?